# how to change envoy configuration dynamically

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I have a kubernetes cluster with 3 node and 3 envoy, I want to change envoy configuration, without losing connection, what is the best solution ???

Comment: [File Based Dynamic Configuration of Routes in Envoy Proxy](https://medium.com/grensesnittet/file-based-dynamic-configuration-of-routes-in-envoy-proxy-6234dae968d2)

Answer (score 1):

[*Envoy*](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/) as an intermediate L7 proxy manager, brings a lot of features and benefits that could probably simplify a general micro services design. Despite the fact that Envoy offers [Static](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/configuration/overview/v2_overview#static) bootstrap configuration, it worth to mentioned about [Dynamic](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/intro/arch_overview/dynamic_configuration#dynamic-configuration) configuration, leveraging a mechanism of auto-discovering configuration settings.

Here are the list of APIs supported dynamic configuration:

- *[Endpoint Discovery Service (EDS) API](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/api-v2/api/v2/eds.proto#envoy-api-file-envoy-api-v2-eds-proto)*;
- [*Cluster Discovery Service (CDS)*](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/configuration/cluster_manager/cds#config-cluster-manager-cds);
- *[Route Discovery Service (RDS)](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/configuration/http_conn_man/rds#config-http-conn-man-rds)*;
- *[Listener Discovery Service (LDS)](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/configuration/listeners/lds#config-listeners-lds)*;
- [Secret Discovery Service (SDS)](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/configuration/secret#config-secret-discovery-service).

For instance, as long as you wish to setup discovery service for [*Route*](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/api-v2/api/v2/route/route.proto.html?highlight=route#http-route) resource you might probaly look at **RDS**; [*Clusters*](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/api-v2/api/v2/cds.proto#cluster), [*Listeners*](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/api-v2/api/v2/lds.proto#envoy-api-msg-listener) and [*Endpoints*](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/api-v2/api/v2/endpoint/endpoint.proto.html?highlight=endpoint): **CDS**, **LDS**, and **EDS** respectively.

Appreciate @Kamol Hasan for his efforts and the good links on the related materials to this topic.